# ComboBox with multiple columns - search by key

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox that displays 2 columns. Now I would like to enable to search by key on all columns. Example:

```
Column1 | Column2
A1      | S1
A2      | B1
A3      | P1
```

The search by key on the first column works fine with default Implementation of KeySelectionManager for JComboBox. However, I would also like to be able to search for the second column as well, meaning when I press 'B' the second item is selected.

I have taken a look at the KeySelectionManager but didn't find anything useful. I have attached a screenshot of the ComboBox to show what I mean.

Thanks for any pointers.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check KeySelectionManager implemetation in JComboBox's source code

```
class DefaultKeySelectionManager implements KeySelectionManager, Serializable {
    public int selectionForKey(char aKey,ComboBoxModel aModel) {
....
       for ( i = ++currentSelection, c = aModel.getSize() ; i < c ; i++ ) {
            Object elem = aModel.getElementAt(i);
            if (elem != null && elem.toString() != null) {
                v = elem.toString().toLowerCase();
                if ( v.length() > 0 && v.charAt(0) == aKey )
                    return i;
            }
        }
```

So try to override your model's Element's class toString() method to include both columns.

Comment: I'd suggest to delay next, another match by using Swing Timer 0,5 - 1 second

Answer (score 1):

If you display two columns in the combo box then you must be using a custom renderer.

So maybe the approach presented in [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) can help. The solution in the blog combines the renderer and KeySelectionManager into a single class. All you need to do is implement the `getDisplayValue()` method to return the text to renderer.

In your case you have two pieces of text to render and search, so you might be able to just change the `getDisplayValue()` method to return List of text you want to display.

Then the renderer can use both items in the List and the `getNextMatch()` method of the class would also be modified to check each item in the list for a match.